# Parse HTML page with sub-headings using XQuery

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, xquery

I have a HTML page which has the following structure:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2><span class="heading">Section A</span></h2>
    <p>Content of the section</p>
    <p>More content in the same section</p>
    <div>We can also have divs</div>
    <ul><li>And</li><li>Lists</li><li>Too</li></ul>
    <h3><span class="heading">Sub-section heading</span></h3>
    <p>The content here can be a mixture of divs, ps, lists, etc too</p>
    <h2><span class="heading">Section B</span></h2>
    <p>This is section B's content</p>
    and so on
</div>
```

I want to create the following XML structure:

```
<sections>
    <section>
        <heading>Section A</heading>
        <content>
            <p>Content of the section</p>
            <p>More content in the same section</p>
            <div>We can also have divs</div>
            <ul><li>And</li><li>Lists</li><li>Too</li></ul>
        </content>
        <sub-sections>
            <section>
                <heading>Section B</heading>
                <content>
                    <p>This is section B's content</p>
                </content>
            </section>
        </sub-sections>
    </section>
</sections>
```

The difficulty I'm having is creating the `<sub-section>` tags. This is what I have so far but Section B appears within the `<content>` node of Section A. I also get a `<section>` node for Section B but it has no content.

```
let $content := //div[@id="content"]
let $headings := $content/(h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)[span[@class="heading"]]
return
  <sections>
  {
    for $heading in $headings
    return
      <section>
        <heading>{$heading/span/text()}</heading>
        <content>
        {
          for $paragraph in $heading/following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h2[1] = $heading]
          return
            $paragraph
        }
        </content>
      </section>
  }
  </sections>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first isolate the data from a section into a variable and then continue processing that:

```
let $content := //div[@id="content"]
return
  <sections>
  {
    for $heading in $content//h2[span[@class='heading'] ] 
    let $nextHeading := $heading/following-sibling::h2
    let $sectionCntent := $heading/following-sibling::* except ($nextHeading,     $nextHeading/following-sibling::*)
    return
      <section>
        {$sectionContent}
      </section>
  }
  </sections>
```

Here I've only done it for section only, then you can process sub-sections by doing a similar thing again on the $sectionContent variable, except now you have to do something a bit freaky to select the first bit or you section (do something similar for the other bit):

```
$sectionContent except ($sectionContent[self::h3], $sectionContent[self::h3]/following-sibling::*)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this set me off on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

In *XQuery 3.0* you can use [`window` clauses](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-windows) to group your sections and sub-sections quite elegantly:

```
<sections>{
  for tumbling window $section in //div[@id = 'content']/*
      start $h2 when $h2 instance of element(h2)
  return <section>{
    <heading>{$h2//text()}</heading>,
    $section/self::h3[1]/preceding-sibling::*,
    <sub-sections>{
      for tumbling window $sub-section in $section
          start $h3 when $h3 instance of element(h3)
      return <section>{
        <heading>{$h3//text()}</heading>,
        tail($sub-section)
      }</section>
    }</sub-sections>
  }</section>
}</sections>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to XQuery 3.0, or at least not all of it. I'm using MarkLogic version 7.